# Fill property based on another ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core

I'm new to ASP.Net Core and C#, and I'm trying to "bind" two properties together. My project involves a SQLite db of a business group. I have companies and branches, and I'm trying to automatically update the "Company Title" property of a branch after "CompanyID" is selected from a dropdown. The editing process takes place in a popup window with a form, inside of which are tabs. I've tried to find a related event without any luck. Any suggestions?

```
.Editing(e => e
    .Mode(GridEditMode.Popup)
    .Form(form => form.Items(items =>
    {
      items.AddTabbed()
           .TabPanelOptions(a => a.Width(950))
        .Tabs(item => item.Add()
                          .Title("Branch Details")
                          .ColCount(2)
                          .Items(tabItems =>
                           {
                             tabItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.BranchCode);
                             tabItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.BranchDescr);
                             tabItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.CompanyId);
                             tabItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.CompanyCode);
                             tabItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.CompanyDescr);
                           }));
    }))
```

Comment: Could you please share your relevant code snippet in order to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I added the part of my code where the popup is being created. If anything else can be useful please let me know.

Comment: From your shared code it's not pretty clear what you are trying however, which client side framework are you using?

Comment: Bootstrap I think. The project was created with devextreme

Comment: Hows's your server side code and which two properties you would like to bind together?

Comment: I used the 'Add Scaffolded Item' option to create the controller and the view, so their code is exactly as visual studio wrote it. The properties are: 
    public int CompanyId{ get; set; }
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public string CompanyDescr { get; set; } . I want to bind the two later to the ID

Comment: Correction: The scaffolder is a devextreme tool. If you wish to review it i will provide it to you, but it's a bit long for a thread.

Comment: Thanks for your response along with details. Actually, this can be done either in server side or in client side. You could have look if your client side framework you are using has the way to achieve it.